# Submitting HTTPs from node socket with no certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

A web application i developed is sitting on a server that serves it under https, some of my js code requires to open a socket to another server (nodejs) who is currently not set for https. and thus browser wont allow it to run.

all i want is a simple way without getting involved with certificates just to initiate a https socket connection, i don't mind the lack of security,
just need app to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificates are not your problem. Your problem is [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-node-js). You need to configure your server to answer with a header allows foreign-origin

> res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'example.com');

because in your case the technical difference between http (port 80) and https (443) is the [port](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_standardisierten_Ports).

**EDIT**: ... I mean from the browsers point of view